# Specflow - Is there a way to manage a background so that it only runs for certain scenarios in a feature?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, specflow, gherkin

I have a Specflow .feature file containing a number of scenarios.

The majority of the scenarios within the feature file use a background. However, one scenario does not require this background.

How can I stop the background from running for this specific scenario without having to move it to a separate feature?

Comment: There is no native way to do this. As an ugly workaround, you can tag certain scenario's with `@nobackground`. In the background steps, you can test if this tag is present in the `ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags` collection and skip the step if so. Be aware that you cannot see if a step is a background step or a scenario step, so the "skip on certain tags" functionality will also work on the scenario steps, leaving you with undesired behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Options I can think of:

- Move the code from a background to a step definition and call this explicitly in each scenario that needs it.
- Use a tag to skip the functionality in the step definition

Moving the steps from  the background seems the best solution as they are not really background any more, they are some sort of setup, which is specific to a scenario. I would create a single step which called all of the steps currently in the background, and call this single step in the scenarios that need it